# Basic height percentage

Tags: css

I don't understand how height percentages work.

Why is the following snippet not filled with color?

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#div1 {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the `html`'s `height` as well.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#div1 {
  height: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}
#div2 {
  height: 80%;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `height: 100%` to `<html>` as well:

```css
html,body {
    height:100%;
}

#div1 {
    height: 20%;
    background-color: red;
}

#div2 {
    height: 80%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code:

```
html,body {
 height:100%;
}
```